# how can we get 1 as output for positive numbers, and 0 as an output for negative numbers

Tags: functions

How can we get a function $f(x)$, such that:

$$f(x)=0 \text{ for } x<0$$
    $$f(x)=1 \text{ for }x>0$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be

> $$f(x) = \frac{x+|x|}{2x}$$

For $x<0, |x| = -x \implies f(x) = \frac{x-x}{2x}=0$

For $x>0, |x| = x \implies f(x) = \frac{2x}{2x} = 1$

We can also write (Thanks to @Luke Collins - stated in comment) $$f(x) = \frac{x+x\ \text{sgn}(x)}{2x} = \frac{1+ \text{sgn}(x)}{2}$$

where $\text{sgn}(x)$ is the signum function. For $x<0 , \text{sgn}(x) = -1$ and for $x>0 , \text{sgn}(x) = 1$.

Comment: Equivalently, $f(x)=\frac12(1+\mathrm{sgn}(x))$.

Comment: Thanks @LukeCollins I've added it :)

Answer (score 1):

You can take piecewise function, for example:

> $$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{l}0,\mathbb{if}\;x\leq0\\1,\mathbb{if}\;x>0\end{array}\right.$$

Therefore $\forall x<0,f(x)=0$ and $\forall x>0, f(x)=1$

Comment: Students usually say "that's cheating, it's not a _real_ function" :)

Comment: No, actually, the answer and question has no difference, it's the same thing, which I have written in the question, but still, thanks